# Create new course from teacher

Tags: moodle

I want to create new course by teacher in moodle. Now only admin can create new course and upload file in my moodle.I define admin,teacher,student in my moodle.To upload file by teacher .I want to know where i change permission, teacher can upload file and create new course. pls

Answer (score 1):

Teachers don't have permission to create courses.

There are three things you can do

1. Make the teachers that you want to allow creating courses Course Creators
   (See http://docs.moodle.org/22/en/Course_creator_role) this is what I do btw.
2. You can modify the default permissions for teachers to allow them to also create courses (See default permissions)
3. You can duplicate the standard role 'teacher' and create a new role called 'teacher+' or something and give that role permission to create courses.

Option 1 is by far the easiest :)

Answer (score 1):

To override the default teacher's permission check moodle doc  -

http://docs.moodle.org/23/en/Permissions#Course_and_activity_permissions

To create course and upload file following capabilities are responsible so you need to allow these capabilities for teacher -

http://docs.moodle.org/23/en/Capabilities/moodle/course:create
http://docs.moodle.org/23/en/Capabilities/moodle/course:managefiles